# How to install two Skim apps on mac?

Tags: macos, mac, pdf, pdf-reader

Skim may be the only pdf viewer that support forward and inverse sync. It only supports one editor for inverse sync. I want to know whether I can install two skim apps with different setting files in `~/Library/Preferences` folder.

Answer (score 0):

To run concurrently? I doubt it unless the developers included a flag you can throw at start-up. If you don't need to run them at the same time, you could write a simple bash script to change a symlink from `Preferences/Skim-A -> Preferences/Skim` to `Preferences/Skim-B - Preferences/Skim` or the like prior to launching the app.

A better idea would be to contact the developer(s), who appear to be fairly active as ask your question.